# rmarkdown powerpoint: two kable on one slide

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint

In this example each `kable` is produced on one slide, even though the slide is large enough for 2.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: ""
date: "2/2/2022"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.height=5, fig.width=10)
```


## Slide with R Output

```{r}
knitr::kable(head(summary(cars),2))
```

```{r}
knitr::kable(head(summary(cars),2))
```
````

gives the output:
[image]

How do I make both `kable` on one slide one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gridExtra package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html
The documentation provides additional details about controlling formatting. I provided one example for illustration.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
t1 <- 
head(summary(cars),2) %>% 
  tableGrob(theme = ttheme_minimal(), rows = NULL)

tt3 <- ttheme_minimal(
  core=list(bg_params = list(fill = blues9[1], 
                             col=NA),
            fg_params=list(fontface=3)),
  colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="navyblue", fontface=4L)))


t2 <- 
 head(summary(cars),2) %>% 
  tableGrob(theme = tt3, rows = NULL)

grid.arrange(t1 , t2)
```

[image: Example slides]

[image: example Code]

Comment: I am not sure how to add the code for you to copy since markdown uses ```. I hope the image is sufficient :)

Comment: thanks @Susan, but my tables are wider than the example. they have to go on top of each other. I tried your solution but with row instead of column and that did not work

Comment: @Courvoisier I refined my response to provide an example of top/bottom display rather than side-by-side display

Comment: Sorry again, I know about the `tableGrob` method. I am specifically asking about `kable`. Because I can manipulate the table format and look much better with `kable`.